# How to fix TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

Hello i am setting a code for rmse but it happen error

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

data=[[235,591],[216,539],[148,413],[35,310],[85,308],[204,519],[49,325],[25,332],[173,498],[191,498],[134,392],[99,334],[117,385],[112,387],[162,425],[272,659],[159,400],[159,427],[59,319],[198,522]]

x_data=[x_row[0] for x_row in data]

y_data=[y_row[1] for y_row in data]

a=np.random.randint(0,10)

b=np.random.randint(0,100)

def f(x):
    return b+a*x

def E(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.sum((y-f(x))**2)

n=1e-3

D=1

count=0

error=E(x_data,y_data)


while D>1e-2:

    tmp0=b-n*np.sum((f(x_data)-y_data))
    tmp1=a-n*np.sum((f(x_data)-y_data)*x_data)
    b=tmp0
    a=tmp1
    current_error=E(x_data,y_data)
    D=error-current_error
    count=count+1
    if count % 100 == 0 :
        print(count,a,b,current_error,D)
```

error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return b+a*x
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Comment: `x` is a `list`, you can't use it in a calculation with `int`s - what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: You are trying to multiply and sum a **list** and an **integer**... You cannot multiply lists... So can you explain what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
def f(x):
    return b+a*x
```

In this context, `a` and `b` are being interpreted as integers while `x` is being interpreted as a list.

If your intent is to apply the calculation to every element in `x`, try something like this:

```
def f(x):    
    out = [] 
    for i in x:
        out.append(b+a*i)
    return out
```

You will have similar errors when trying to do more calculations later on where you are using lists in calculations. You will have to make similar changes.

For example:

```
def E(x,y):
    return 0.5*np.sum((y-f(x))**2)
```

Will have to be changed to something like:

```
def E(x,y):
    out = [] 
    for xi, yi in zip(y, f(x)):
        out.append(0.5*np.sum((yi-xi**2)))
    return out
```

To avoid a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`